# Deploying individual or multiple WCF services per IIS application?

Tags: wcf, iis

I am in the middle of an internal debate about IIS hosting. For a given enterprise application we have N WCF services.

One option is to host each WCF service in its own IIS application. This implies each service has its own web.config and [possibly] its own Application Pool.

Another option is to hose all WCF services in one IIS application. This implies one web.config for all those services and one Application Pool.

The individual option gives the flexibility to have different configuration (IIS and web.config) for each service. Individual Application Pools would enable more granular control of resetting the processes.

The shared option is more simple and is possible because the IIS and application configuration (web.config) should be the same for each service.

I am looking for advice\best practice between these two options.

Comment: The advantage of sharing the same **web.config** file for multiple WCF services is that you will be able to define serviceBehaviors, endpointBehaviors, custom bindings, etc that your WCF services use in a single place instead of copying and pasting them in several files. This doesn't mean you should use one IIS application for hosting dozens of WCF services. Maybe a good solution is to group your services by functionality and create a couple of well defined IIS applications.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. To be more clear, in this scenario I am talking about about 5 services for a single enterprise application.

Comment: This is a decision weighing downtime vs ease of configuration.  This is not a "Best Practice" type of question.  Both directions have their merits and neither are a bad practice.

Comment: Having said that, as a general rule I group my services that all relate to the same business need into the same application and pool.  Orders services together, Tracking services together, Products services together, etc.  This way, only related services are brought down together for deployment or other issues.

Comment: @SeanM I keep internally debating this myself. I flip-flop on what I consider the best option. It seems like 1 application pool per service should be preferred because if 1 service locks up an application pool or whatever, the other services wouldn't be affected. I'm not sure how true that statement is, however.

Answer (score 0):

Working in the same type of enterprise environment as the one you describe we find the best practise is as follows:

1. Group similar functions into "Applications" which are then hosted under one WCF service. This gives us e.g. CustomerService, AccountsService etc.
2. Each service has its own App. Domain to give it process separation and security separation from the other services. That is, each service runs under the context of an ActiveDiretory (AD) account and doing this allows us secure downstream resources such as SQL server databases.

E.g. CustomerService runs under DOMAIN\CustomerServiceUser user. We can then secure for example stored procedures related to customer functions so they can only be executed by the CustomerServiceUser user. We can then use integrated security for our connection to the SQL server. This allows enterprise permissions to be managed at the Active Directory level.

3. We deploy using scripting for both the IIS configuration and our web.config files. This has the advantage that the IIS configuration can also be kept in source control as can the transform files for our web.config files. We then have full version history or our configuration and additionally can use this to quickly roll out additional machines if we decide to duplicate & load balance the services.

This is what we find to be the best practise although the requirements of your organisation may be different.